# Creating graph in service now with difference in two columns

Tags: servicenow

I am trying to create a graph in servicenow. I clicked add new widget and selected source as table and i mentioned my tablename. In the query builder i have selected options for all the incidents solved by our team. Everything works fine. Actual issue is i need to get the graph of average time which will be calculated based on difference between two columns. The column of average time will not be present in the table. I am not finding any option to find difference while selecting query.

I tried creating the graph for incidents table. I am expecting the average time value to be populated in graph, but i am getting incidents value in graph. The average time value must be calculated based on difference between two values

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question.